# Resetting plugins while URL call

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2, inappbrowser

When i try to call the url in my phone-gap 2.9.0 application in ios,The application become blank and url loading not in inappbrowser.
Here the code

**Config.xml**

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

Method

```
var indexpnl = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        id: 'indexpnl',
        scrollable:'vertical',
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        html:'<div align="center" ><img src="resources/img/img1.png" height="280px" width="100%" /><br><div style="padding:10px;" align="center"><img id="btnlogin" src="resources/img/buttonlogin.png" height="42px" width="100%"  /><br><img src="resources/img/buttonfacebook.png" id="btnfacebook"  height="42px" width="100%"/><br><div align="center">or</div><img src="resources/img/buttonsignup.png" id="register" height="42px" width="100%"/></div></div>'

        });
        indexpnl.element.on({
        tap: function (e) {
            var el = Ext.get(e.target);
            var bval = el.getId();
            if (bval == "btnlogin") {
                goLogin()
            }
             if (bval == "btnfacebook")
            {
                 var ref = window.open('http://www.facebook.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
                 ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
                 ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
                 ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
            }
             if (bval == "register") {
                register()
            }
        }
    });
```

And the NSLOG return

```
  [3475:c07]  Resetting plugins due to page load.
```

How to call the URL in inappbrowser.PLease help me to solve